# Add additional user information to SPList as list column

Tags: splistitem, calculated-column, splist

I have a List Tickets with a field `Client`. This is a user from our AD and displays the name of the user.

We now need to display the country and the location the user resides in to additional fields.
Is it possible to add those fields in the form of calculated fields based on the user in the `Client` field? If yes - how?

If not: Could you guide me to the appropriate documentation or resources on how to implement this in the form of code. There are 2 eventhandlers active on this list, handling incoming mails and itemchanges, so I could place the logic there if need be, but right now I desperatly need a starting point, since I am totally lost.

This is a prototype of where I am so far:

```
SPWeb web = new SPSite("http://myserver/path/sitecollection").OpenWeb();
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(@"domain\Servdev");
SPListItem item = web.SiteUserInfoList.Items.GetItemById(user.ID);

Console.WriteLine("{0} -- {1}",item.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Department], item.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Office]);

Console.ReadLine();
```

This displays the name of the fields I want to have, but not the values stored in it and I can't access them.
Kind regards

**//EDIT:**
Apparently, `SPBuiltInFieldId.Office` Guid is not valid across the board. So instead you'd have to use `item["Office"]` or the localized version of your site. (in my case `item["Büro"]` does work too.

But all in all, the answer given by Naim is totally correct.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} -- {1}",item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Department] == null ? "N/A" : item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Department].ToString(), item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Office] == null ? "N/A" : item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Office].ToString());
```

In the event receivers you can set those two columns.

With calculated columns would be great but as far as I know that's not possible for your case.

Comment: This is the error I am getting: `Invalid field name. {26169ab2-4bd2-4870-b077-10f49c8a5822}  /project/sitecollection/_catalogs/users`

Comment: then better go with UserProfileManager

Comment: `Office` field doesn't have the same id on all webs and it's not equal to `SPBuiltInFieldId.Office`. You can take the value of this field just by it's name: item["Office"].ToString()

Comment: I found the error, I am marking you as correct and edit my original post to clarify, where the excact problem was.

Comment: Evgeny, that was exactly what I just discovered myself.